# Looping thru JSON using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How do you filter a records in JSON Array using Python? 
Here's my Python code:

[image]

Sample Data Source: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dwh-test-resources/recipes.json

In the "ingredients" i need to filter all records that contain bread. all string contain bread under the "ingredients" regardless if the string bread is upper case, lower case, plural or singular i should be able to filter it.

My python version is 3.

Comment: What does the current code do? What **exactly** is missing? What have you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say:

```
data = [{...json you have}]
```

Now we will check:

```
res = []
for i in data:
    if 'bread' in i["ingredients"].lower():
        res.append(i)
```

or simply:

```
res = [i for i in data if 'bread' in i["ingredients"].lower()]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried to plug it on my existing python code but i am receiving this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: are you sure data is a json?